# Help With Complex Number Sequence

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the $n$ complex numbers $z_1 , z_2 , z_3 , \dots , z_n$, such that $|z_k| = 1 $  for any $1\leq k\leq n$
and $z_1 \cdot  z_2 \cdot z_3 \cdots \cdot z_n = 1$.
I need to prove that 
$$(1+z_1) \cdot (1 + z_2) \cdots   (1 + z_n)$$ 
is a real number.

Comment: Hint: Express $ 1 + z_1$ in another form.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w:=\prod_k(1+z_k)$ so $w^\ast=\prod_k(1+z_k^\ast)=\prod_k(1+z_k^{-1})=w/\prod_kz_k=w$. Since $w^\ast=w$, $w\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: There is more simpler solution without exp and $\prod$?

Comment: @xx01 See edit for an $\exp$-free solution. The only way to avoid $\prod$ is to use $\cdots$ for the product notation.

Comment: Ok I am understand what is $ \prod $. Can you explain me please why w =  w*? And why $ w\in\Bbb R$ if w = w*? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @xx01 $\prod_kz_k=1\implies w^\ast/w=1$. Any non-real complex number satisfies $w^\ast\ne w$.

Comment: More one last thing why  $\prod_k(1+z_k^{-1})=w/\prod_kz_k$ ? I am very appreciate your help!

Comment: @xx01 Using $1+z_k^{-1}=(1+z_k)/z_k$.

Comment: Thank for all the help!